# CommandBinding to a Command located inside a Module breaks visual designer

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio

I want to organize Commands inside separated Module. When I am creating binding to a Command in XAML file inside Window.CommandBindings Visual studio prints out error message **The name "MyCommands" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MyAwesomeProgram"** & visual designer refuses to render XAML markup with message **"Invalid Markup"**. Although project builds & program runs fine. Command binding works. As opposed to this there is no such problem with C# projects & bindings to Commands inside C# static class.

Tried to rebuild project. Tried to put Module in namespace.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyAwesomeProgram">
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:MyCommands.ShowPreferences}" Executed="ShowPreferences_Executed"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
```

Comment: Have you tried to include the assembly name in the `xmlsn` reference: `xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:MyAwesomeProgram;assembly=MyCommandAssembly"`?

Comment: No. What the point? How it is different from xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyAwesomeProgram">?